# JS - Get original value of string replace using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a string:

```
var dynamicString = "This isn't so dynamic, but it will be in real life.";
```

User types in some input:

```
var userInput = "REAL";
```

I want to match on this input, and wrap it with a span to highlight it:

```
var result = " ... but it will be in <span class='highlight'>real</span> life.";
```

So I use some RegExp magic to do that:

```
// Escapes user input,
var searchString = userInput.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");

// Now we make a regex that matches *all* instances 
// and (most important point) is case-insensitive.
var searchRegex = new RegExp(searchString , 'ig');

// Now we highlight the matches on the dynamic string:
dynamicString = dynamicString.replace(reg, '<span class="highlight">' + userInput + '</span>');
```

This is all great, except here is the result:

```
console.log(dynamicString);
// -> " ... but it will be in <span class='highlight'>REAL</span> life.";
```

I replaced the content with the *user's input*, which means the text now gets the user's dirty case-insensitivity.

How do I wrap all matches with the span shown above, while maintaining the original value of the matches?

Figured out, the ideal result would be:

```
// user inputs 'REAL',

// We get:
console.log(dynamicString);
// -> " ... but it will be in <span class='highlight'>real</span> life.";
```

Comment: Have you tried userInput.toLowerCase()...

Comment: Wouldn't work, because if the user searched 1366 Mulberry Lane, the matching result will then show all lowercase, when it should be Proper Cased.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd use regex capturing groups and backreferences to capture the match and insert it in the string

```
var searchRegex = new RegExp('('+userInput+')' , 'ig');
dynamicString = dynamicString.replace(searchRegex, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/22J7k/)

Comment: It may be preferable to escape certain characters which have meaning in _RegExp_ or _HTML_, e.g. `<>[]?^$`

Comment: Wow. 8 years of web development and somehow I have never, ever heard of backreferences or seen their use. +100.

Comment: @Paul S., If you look at my code above, you'll see I already do that.

Comment: @PaulS. - there's an escaping replace() on the user input in the OP's code, so I figured that was already taken care of.

Comment: @dc2 - now you know how they work, and it can be really useful sometimes

Comment: For sure! Worked like a charm - definitely using them in the future!

Comment: No problem, also note the parenthesis added to the user input, they are needed to create the capturing group.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it without capturing groups too.

```
dynamicString = text.replace(new RegExp(userInput, 'ig'), '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
```